# Trim node inside views

Tags: drupal, chars, trim

I have a view (Drupal 7), filled with nodes. And I got a trimmer on 200 chars on the body. But as it happens, somethimes a word is cut in half. How do I get to trimm Drupal on words in stead of chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `Rewrite results` field options and underneath the checkbox entitled `Trim this field to a maximum length` make sure the checkbox entitled `Trim only on a word boundary` is selected.